# Ubuntu server 16.04 stops during boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, systemd

I have upgraded an Ubuntu server from 12 (to 14 and then) to 16. It was working fine for a few months, but then I had to reboot. After the reboot it doesn't boot successfully anymore.

I can get into rescue mode, but the normal boot doesn't work/finish. The last messages are "OK Reached target Sockets." and "Starting Nameserver Information manager..."

If I use Alt+F2...F6 I get a blank screen and enter doesn't work, so I can't login on a different terminal and check the status of the systemd services.

The network doesn't come up, so I also can't login via ssh.

In rescue mode I can activate the network and start sshd manually. I have checked the disks, everything seems ok. Nothing relevant in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages.

I don't know how to debug the boot process with systemd.

Comment: As starting point you need to use `journalctl` to check `systemd` logs and `systemctl` and `systemd-analyze` to analyze system state.

Comment: It was a good starting point, but unfortunately the logs weren't very helpful in rescue mode. I have eventually managed to debug the normal boot procedure by enabling the debug shell on tty 9 with: systemctl enable debug-shell (it opens up a root terminal accessible with alt+F9 whenre i could diagnose all the problems)

Answer (score 0):

> Starting Nameserver Information manager...

It is handled by `/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf.service`. You may want to check `resolvconf` manually in rescue mode.